# Can't install conan recipe from Artifactory OSS server from Bamboo server

Tags: artifactory, bamboo, conan

I have JFrog Artifactory Community Edition 7.11.2 for C++ installed on a linux server and from my Windows pc I can successfully install required recipes for a project via the `conan install ..` command. However when I use the same files and scripts on my Bamboo Server (windows) as a build plan I get the following error:

`ERROR: Couldn't read login`

Conan suggests:

`Try removing 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.conan\.conan.db' file.`

This I have done but still get the same error.
The Bamboo server runs using the Local System Account.

Are there recommended practices for using Conan with Bamboo for CI uses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had surplus `"`'s in the remotes.txt file. I had a line like this...

`"conancenter"  "https://center.conan.io" true` when it should of been

`conancenter  https://center.conan.io true`

Answer (score 0):

By default, Anonymous user is disabled, which means, only authenticated users can upload or download packages from Artifactory.

If your Bamboo instance is only downloading, without authentication, so first you need to enable the anonymous user access: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Users+and+Groups#UsersandGroups-ManagingUsers

Only administrator account can do it.

[image]

Comment: Thank for the reply, I had already done that!

Comment: Did work? Please,  update your question, so other users can learn from your problem.

Comment: No didn't work. Have the same problem when I try the `conan install ..` command from the command line on the same PC.

Comment: Another interesting fact is that you are using Conan cache folder under System32, which is abnormal. Probably we have permission limitation due your user. I would suggest customizing the conan cache path by [CONAN_USER_HOME](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/env_vars.html#conan-user-home). You can point to `C:\Users\<uername>\`

Comment: Tried that and set the permissions for everyone, SYSTEM, localAccount to full access for the directory too! But still get the same error.

Comment: Could this be a clue... I opened the .conan.db file using  DB Browser for SQLite (https://sqlitebrowser.org/) and discovered that the users_remotes table was empty. When I did the same on my PC it had 2 entries.